# Powershell Websocket Client Send Image

Tags: image, powershell, websocket, client, send

With reference to the solution to provided by Vince Pike here: 
[How to use a Websocket client to open a long-lived connection to a URL, using PowerShell V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257671/how-to-use-a-websocket-client-to-open-a-long-lived-connection-to-a-url-using-po)

Sending text is working well. How do i send image such as PNG format or binary data?

Example source of sending text:

```
$Size = 1024
$Array = [byte[]] @(,0) * $Size
$Message = "Sample Message"
$Command = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Message)
$Send = New-Object System.ArraySegment[byte] -ArgumentList @(,$Command)            
$Conn = $WS.SendAsync($Send, [System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType]::Text, $true, $CT)
While (!$Conn.IsCompleted) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

Comment: Can you try `[Byte[]]$Command = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(<Absolute\Path\To\The\Image\Or\Binary\File>)` and send like `$Conn = $WS.SendAsync($Send, [System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType]::Binary, $true, $CT)` ?

Comment: That solves it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by @Theo Solves it:

```
[Byte[]]$Command = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(<Absolute\Path\To\The\Image\Or\Binary\File>) 
$Conn = $WS.SendAsync($Send, [System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType]::Binary, $true, $CT)
```