# Scrape webpage using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to scrape a webpage.
I specifically need to extract the section "USDT Funding Market" on the page.

```
$WebExtract = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.kucoin.com/margin/lend/USDT"
```

Although `$WebExtract.content` or `$WebExtract.AllElements` does not contain the "USDT Funding Market".

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that your initial web request is only returning you the HTML of the page, however a lot of modern web applications like this have some JavaScript under the hood that will reach out to their API's and fill the page with data *after* the initial HTML is loaded.

The good news is, usually with public websites like this you can hit the underlying API's without worrying about authentication - which actually makes parsing the data easier, as it's typically in JSON format.

Try opening the debug console in your browser *(usually F12)*, open the network tab and refresh the page - you can typically find these API requests/endpoints in there, e.g;

[image]

Simply copy that URL out and invoke the web request to the API instead, for example;

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.kucoin.com/_api/currency/prices?base=USD&targets='
$json = $request.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.data
```

This might not be the specific API endpoint/data you're after, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. If you poke around in the console you *should* be able to find the one you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

Apologies for the misleading information here, I didn't notice that these numbers were updating in real time on the site. The above is still pretty common for a lot of websites so I'll leave it, however on sites that are this responsive/live another common technology used is Web Sockets.

If you have a look at the last lines of the console, you should be able to see a request ending with '`transport=websocket`' to a URL like this;

```
wss://ws-web.kucoin.com/socket.io/?token=...%3D%3D&format=json&acceptUserMessage=false&connectId=connect_welcome&EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

If you select this line and head over to the *Messages* tab in your browser console/debugger, you'll be able to see the web socket messages being returned;

[image]

This looks like the data you're after, but I'm not hugely familiar with querying Web Sockets through PowerShell.

Simply invoking a web request won't work here, as it's using the web sockets protocol to handle the communication. You would also need to find a way to get a valid token for opening a web sockets connection *(likely just a web request for that)*.

Perhaps these posts will help;

- http://wragg.io/powershell-slack-bot-using-the-real-time-messaging-api/
- [How to use a Websocket client to open a long-lived connection to a URL, using PowerShell V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257671/how-to-use-a-websocket-client-to-open-a-long-lived-connection-to-a-url-using-po)

Comment: @ elkenyo Thanks for the details.I went though the list of URLs under Network, But all I could find relevant was, https://www.kucoin.com/margin/lend/USDT

Comment: Ah, my apologies @hdsouza - I've edited the original post. Looks like the data you're after is using Web Sockets, so this is going to be a little more complicated than I thought... Going to run of of time today, but will try check back in on this.