# Downloading Circular File from NSE

Tags: powershell, automation

Code intends to download the file attached to link ;

```
$Url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/circulars?&fromDate=06-06-2023&toDate=13-06-2023&csv=true";

$outfile = "G:\My Drive\Surveillance\test.csv";
Invoke-WebRequest $Url -OutFile $outfile
```

Just keeps running without any error.Also does not download file.

> original page :
> *https://www.nseindia.com/resources/exchange-communication-circulars*

I have tried the below options as well;

1. Using headers :[Invoke webrequest fails to fetch website data even though works in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225983/invoke-webrequest-fails-to-fetch-website-data-even-though-works-in-all-browsers)
2. Invoke-RestMethod
3. Invoke-WebRequest -Uri & Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing

Other downloads work perfectly for me ;

```
Invoke-WebRequest > "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_$($DateReformat).csv" -OutFile 
 "$($SystemPath)Source\dailyPOI.csv";
```

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Why do you have $outfile twice in the command?  Remove "$outfile = "

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Navigating to the URL you give doesn't lead to a CSV file, but a normal web page with the contents in an HTML table - simply saving it to a CSV file isn't going to work.  You'll either need to get a direct URL for the CSV file or parse the page yourself to extract the data.

Comment: @boxdog ,Parsing the web page did retrieve all required data .Edited the link , wanted to learn the workaround for the same ;when link has "API" .

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are trying to scrape circular,this worked for me as an alternative .

> ```
> $web  = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.nseindia.com/api/circulars
> $json = $web.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
> $Source += $json.Table;
> ```

Perhaps , this will help ;
[Scrape webpage using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694696/scrape-webpage-using-powershell)