# Get html file value from powershell

Tags: html, windows, powershell

We have a html file that is used to test whether a internal tool is properly installed or not.

The html file outputs two values Connected or Connection failed.

Below is the screenshot, when we opened the html file through browser.

[image]

I need above values to be output via PowerShell terminal.

I tried Invoke-Webrequest but couldnt get the required values.

```
Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html | Select content
```

### Content

{60, 33, 68, 79...}

```
Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html | Select-Object -ExpandProperty rawcontent
Content-Length: 886
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset = "utf-8" />
   <title>WebSocket Test</title>

   <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
      var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9091/";
      var output;
    
      function init() {
         output = document.getElementById("output");
         testWebSocket();
      }
    
      function testWebSocket() {
         websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
            
         websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
            onOpen(evt)
         };

     websocket.onclose = function(evt){
        onClose(evt)
     };
      }

    function onClose(evt) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'CONNECTION FAILED';
    }
    
      function onOpen(evt) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'CONNECTED';

      }
    
      window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
   
   </script>

   <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
   <div id = "output"></div>

</html>
```

Any help?

Edited:
(Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html).Content
60, 33, 68, 79, 67, 84, 89, 80, 69, 32, 104,    116,    109,    108,    62, 10, 60, 104,    116,    109,    108,    62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 109,    101,    116,    97, 32, 99, 104,    97, 114,    115,    101,    116,    32, 61, 32, 34, 117,    116,    102,    45, 56, 34, 32, 47, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 116,    105,    116,    108,    101,    62, 87, 101,    98, 83, 111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    32, 84, 101,    115,    116,    60, 47, 116,    105,    116,    108,    101,    62, 10, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 115,    99, 114,    105,    112,    116,    32, 108,    97,
110,    103,    117,    97, 103,    101,    32, 61, 32, 34, 106,    97, 118,    97, 115,    99, 114,    105,    112,    116,    34, 32, 116,    121,    112,    101,    32, 61, 32, 34, 116,    101,    120,    116,    47, 106,    97, 118,    97, 115,    99, 114,    105,    112,    116,    34, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 118,    97, 114,    32, 119,    115,    85, 114,    105,    32, 61, 32, 34, 119,    115,    58, 47, 47, 108,    111,    99, 97, 108,    104,    111,    115,    116,    58, 57, 48, 57, 49, 47, 34, 59, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 118,    97, 114,    32,
111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    59, 10, 9,  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    32, 105,    110,    105,    116,    40, 41, 32, 123,    10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    32, 61, 32, 100,    111,    99, 117,    109,    101,    110,    116,    46, 103,    101,    116,    69, 108,    101,    109,    101,    110,    116,    66, 121,    73, 100,    40, 34, 111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    34, 41, 59, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 116,    101,    115,    116,
101,    98, 83, 111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    40, 41, 59, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125,    10, 9,  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    32, 116,    101,    115,    116,    87, 101,    98, 83, 111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    40, 41, 32, 123,    10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 119,    101,    98, 115,    111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    32, 61, 32, 110,    101,    119,    32, 87, 101,    98, 83, 111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    40, 119,    115,    85, 114,    105,    41, 59, 10, 9,  9,
10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 119,    101,    98, 115,    111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    46, 111,    110,    111,    112,    101,    110,    32, 61, 32, 102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 32, 123,    10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 111,    110,    79, 112,    101,    110,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125,    59, 10, 10, 9,  32, 119,    101,    98, 115,    111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    46, 111,    110,    99, 108,    111,    115,
101,    32, 61, 32, 102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 123,    10, 9,  9,  111,    110,    67, 108,    111,    115,    101,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 10, 9,  32, 125,    59, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125,    10, 10, 9,  102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    32, 111,    110,    67, 108,    111,    115,    101,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 32, 123,    10, 9,  9,  100,    111,    99, 117,    109,    101,    110,    116,    46, 103,    101,    116,    69, 108,    101,    109,    101,    110,    116,    66, 121,    73, 100,    40, 39,
111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    39, 41, 46, 105,    110,    110,    101,    114,    72, 84, 77, 76, 32, 43, 61, 32, 39, 67, 79, 78, 78, 69, 67, 84, 73, 79, 78, 32, 70, 65, 73, 76, 69, 68, 39, 59, 10, 9,  125,    10, 9,  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 102,    117,    110,    99, 116,    105,    111,    110,    32, 111,    110,    79, 112,    101,    110,    40, 101,    118,    116,    41, 32, 123,    10, 9,  100,    111,    99, 117,    109,    101,    110,    116,    46, 103,    101,    116,    69, 108,    101,    109,    101,    110,    116,    66, 121,    73,
100,    40, 39, 111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    39, 41, 46, 105,    110,    110,    101,    114,    72, 84, 77, 76, 32, 43, 61, 32, 39, 67, 79, 78, 78, 69, 67, 84, 69, 68, 39, 59, 10, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125,    10, 9,  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 119,    105,    110,    100,    111,    119,    46, 97, 100,    100,    69, 118,    101,    110,    116,    76, 105,    115,    116,    101,    110,    101,    114,    40, 34, 108,    111,    97, 100,    34, 44, 32, 105,    110,    105,    116,    44, 32, 102,    97, 108,    115,    101,    41, 59,
10, 32, 32, 32, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 47, 115,    99, 114,    105,    112,    116,    62, 10, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 104,    50, 62, 87, 101,    98, 83, 111,    99, 107,    101,    116,    32, 84, 101,    115,    116,    60, 47, 104,    50, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 100,    105,    118,    32, 105,    100,    32, 61, 32, 34, 111,    117,    116,    112,    117,    116,    34, 62, 60, 47, 100,    105,    118,    62, 10, 10, 60, 47, 104,    116,    109,    108,    62, 10

Comment: What does `(Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html).Content` say?

Comment: @Theo: It just outputs series of random numbers.

Comment: Those aren't random numbers,  They are the ascii values of the html text

Comment: `60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109,108,62` spells `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: In order to process the javascript, try checking the `ParsedHtml` property returned by `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of content/rawcontent.

Comment: @Theo: My bad...I had attached the output above

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I tried (Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html).ParsedHtml but it returns nothing.

Comment: Maybe it was just an issue with the copy/paste, but the ascii values show a typo on line 12: `testebSocket();` should be `testWebSocket();`. I'm not sure if powershell will process the javascript in a file like this, BUT you can easily use powershell to do the websocket check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120192/7411885

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "C:\websocket.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-WebRequest` does not actually [handle local html files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989452/7411885). Even though it looks like it is successful, it just... opens the file. This is made more clear in newer versions of powershell (v7.1 below):

```
Invoke-WebRequest C:\websocket.html

[Error] Invoke-WebRequest: Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed. (Parameter 'requestUri')
```

Another option is to use the internet explorer COM objects to basically open the file in IE, and scrape the page:

```
$url = 'C:\websocket.html'
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application  -Property @{visible = $false}
$ie.navigate($url)

# Optionally wait for connection
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){sleep 1}
$output = $ie.Document.documentElement.innerText
# Output the last line of the returned page
$output -split [environment]::NewLine | Select -Last 1
$ie.Quit()

# Outputs:
CONNECTION FAILED
```

If it doesn't look like the output is working, set `visible = $true`, and see if IE is complaining about something (for me, I had to allow ActiveX).

Answer (score -1):

```
$value= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "C:\websocket.html" 
$op = [char[]]$value.Content
$op -join ''
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 